# How to prevent "reverse wheel effect" when drawing a fast rotation?

Tags: android, canvas, rotation, android-canvas

I want to write an spinner game in native android.
I use an asynctask to compute and publish rotation until game is run.
every thing is ok but when rotation speed increased "reverse wheel effect" occurred. and image according to rotation speed seems stopped or even rotate at reverse direction.

How can I draw motion blur for example spinner sims like circle at high rotation speed ?
[image]